# After building react app using webpack, browserRouter does not allow me to go directly to a route, but hashRouter does?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

**My issue**
When I run npm run dev, the app loads up and all is good, I can go to my route defined as  and be able to see the component. However when I do npm run buildDev and load up the app, it loads the "/" route fine, but when i manually go to "/login" it says "cannot get /login"

**what works**
if I were to click the "login" link as set up my "Link" it works fine, even after the build. Then I went into my index.js and changed my browserrouter to hashrouter and then ran buildDev again and npm start, and i was able to go to the login route if i did "/#/login"

**What am I doing wrong here that browser router doesnt work?**

My package.json scripts file is as below as well:

```js
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
  "server": "nodemon server-dev.js",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
  "buildDev": "rimraf build && webpack --mode development --config webpack.server.config.js && webpack --mode development --config webpack.dev.config.js",
  "buildProd": "rimraf build && webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.config.js && webpack --mode production --config webpack.prod.config.js",
  "start": "node ./build/server.bundle.js"
},
```

My webpack.dev.config.js file has the contents below:

```js
module.exports = {
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  mode: "development",
  target: "web",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              camelCase: "dashes",
              localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              ident: "postcss",
              plugins: () => [
                autoprefixer({
                  browsers: [">1%", "last 2 versions"]
                })
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=8000&name=images/[name].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      "/main": {
        target:"http://localhost:8080"
      }
    },
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + "/src/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      inject: "body",
      excludeChunks: ["server"]
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
  }
};
```

My app.js looks like the below:

```js
const AsyncPizza = React.lazy(() => import("./containers/Pizza"));

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
  <Link to="/login">login</Link>     
        <div>
          <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
            <Route path="/login" component={Authentication} />
            <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
            <Route path="/pizza" exact component={AsyncPizza} />
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
My server-dev.js is as follows:

```js
app.use(express.static("build"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
require("./routes")(app);


app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Listening on port 8080!"));
```

My webpack.server.config.js is as follows:

```js
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const SERVER_PATH =
    argv.mode === "production" ? "./server-prod.js" : "./server-dev.js";

  return {
    entry: {
      server: SERVER_PATH
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
      filename: "[name].bundle.js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js",
      publicPath: "/"
    },
    mode: argv.mode,
    target: "node",
    node: {
      // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
      __dirname: false, // if you don't put this is, __dirname
      __filename: false // and __filename return blank or /
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // Need this to avoid error when working with Express
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          // Transpiles ES6-8 into ES5
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
};
```

**EDIT 2:**

In my routes folder I have a index.js file which has the following contents:

```js
module.exports=function(app){
    app.use("/main",require("./main"))
}
```

Then in "main" folder I just have a "test" file which has the following route that is exported:

```js
router.get(
  "/test",
  (req, res) =>

  res.send("hello")


);
```

Comment: How are you trying to load the build version of app ? That's more of a server side problem, not anything with reactjs. Please explain a bit about your server.

Comment: @DJYadav do you mean my server.js file?

Comment: yes, you need to redirect all the routes to load react app inside that, can you paste the contents of that file here?

Comment: @DJYadav just edited my main question and added the two file contents. server-dev.js and webpack.server.config.js

Comment: Still missing the contents of *routes* file in server.js

Comment: Can you post that also ?

Comment: @DJYadav added to edit 2 above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193111/discussion-between-dj-yadav-and-rio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the previous person, you need to add this after your app.use routes part in your server-dev.js

```js
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
})
```

this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this sample of code (In case you are using the server for serving only the react app):

```
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Where you can replace the link of the index.html file as per your file structure.

Comment: But i am doing this in webpack.server.config.js no?

Comment: That is for dev server only when you're working with dev assets only.
When you're building the app, you are actually exporting the assets and you work around with your own server which can be on any platform/language/framework. In this case, you're using server.js file (ExpressJs framework to do that)